# How to add date stamps on the images using Python library to create noise in the image

Tags: python, deep-learning, autoencoder

How to add date stamps on the image frames using Python library to create noise in the image

I tried the below but would like to know how to add it as part of the image frame

from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

import pandas as pd
print(pd.datetime.now())

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pillow/python_pillow_creating_a_watermark.htm) article, you can understand how add watermark on image.
I modified code from that website to add timestamp as watermark using python Pillow library.

```html
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
im = Image.open('image.jpg')
width, height = im.size
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36)
textwidth, textheight = draw.textsize(text, font)
margin = 10
x = width - textwidth - margin
y = height - textheight - margin
draw.text((x, y), text, font=font)
im.show()
im.save('watermark.jpg')
```